# How to ask a question on an accepted answer?

Tags: support

I had asked a question about 6  months ago and I had got an answer to the problem. Now, I have some questions on that problem. Can I leave comments for my questions there?

Comment: You can always post a follow-up question in a separate post. And generally you can leave comments. But you shouldn't change the question itself. (It might help to link to the post you are talking about and give more details.)

Comment: You can leave comments wherever you like, but will anyone see them? Comments don't bump answers to the front page. If you post a new question, please be sure to link it to the original question (and, if appropriate, link the original to the new question, as well).

Comment: If you leave a comment on the answer, then the author of the answer will receive a notice in his "inbox".